# Dynamic Key in Message Property

Tags: java, mule, mel

How to add a dynamic key in `message-properties-transformer` component in Mule ESB.

```
<message-properties-transformer scope="session" doc:name="Message Properties">
    <add-message-property key="#[key]" value="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]"/>
</message-properties-transformer>
```

[image: How to add dynamic key here]

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way you can do this is programmatically, using something like an expression component:

```
<expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[message.outboundProperties.put(flowVars.key, "value");]]></expression-component>
```